# Error while installing oursql in virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql, pip, python-venv, oursql

When I try to install `oursql` under virtual environment using `pip install oursql` I get following error:

```
Collecting oursql
  Using cached oursql-0.9.3.1.tar.bz2
Building wheels for collected packages: oursql
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for oursql
  Complete output from command /home/raghav/janpro/release_1/venv/bin/python2 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ndxBoY/oursql/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpe4k7ejpip-wheel-:
  cython not found, using previously-cython'd .c file.
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  warning: no usable mysql_config and no _winreg module to try; hopefully you have usable CFLAGS/LDFLAGS set.
  building 'oursql' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/oursqlx
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c oursqlx/oursql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/oursqlx/oursql.o
  oursqlx/oursql.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for oursql
Failed to build oursql
Installing collected packages: oursql
  Running setup.py install for oursql
    Complete output from command /home/raghav/janpro/release_1/venv/bin/python2 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ndxBoY/oursql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-awH5dT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/raghav/janpro/release_1/venv/include/site/python2.7/oursql:
    cython not found, using previously-cython'd .c file.
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    warning: no usable mysql_config and no _winreg module to try; hopefully you have usable CFLAGS/LDFLAGS set.
    building 'oursql' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c oursqlx/oursql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/oursqlx/oursql.o
    oursqlx/oursql.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/raghav/janpro/release_1/venv/bin/python2 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ndxBoY/oursql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-awH5dT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/raghav/janpro/release_1/venv/include/site/python2.7/oursql" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ndxBoY/oursql
```

Then I installed `MySQL C++ connectors` with `sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev` but still error was coming.

So, I tried `sudo pip install oursql` and got following output:

```
The directory '/home/raghav/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/raghav/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting oursql
  Downloading oursql-0.9.3.1.tar.bz2 (119kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 122kB 986kB/s 
Installing collected packages: oursql
  Running setup.py install for oursql
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-GbfPiA/oursql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-avSCME-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    cython not found, using previously-cython'd .c file.
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    warning: no usable mysql_config and no _winreg module to try; hopefully you have usable CFLAGS/LDFLAGS set.
    building 'oursql' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/oursqlx
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c oursqlx/oursql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/oursqlx/oursql.o
    oursqlx/oursql.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-GbfPiA/oursql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-avSCME-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-GbfPiA/oursql
```

What is going wrong? I am unable to find out.

Answer (score 1):

```
the directory '/home/raghav/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

I think you installed some library into your virtualenv using `sudo pip`. So now some files are owned by the `root` user and your user cannot write there. You never should use virtualenv as root.

If you have a `requirements.txt` file I think the easiest way is to create a new virtualenv and install everything again. If you don't want/can't do this try to change the permissions with `chown`

Answer (score 1):

You do not have python development libraries installed. Try installing it first, and then running `pip`.

`sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

1. `$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`
2. `$ sudo pip install oursql`